# Psycopg2 : Create a table in a stored procedure Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

**Stored Procedure :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION try_create() RETURNS INT AS $$

  BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE hello(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
      RETURN 1;
  END ;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**test.py**

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(user='a', password='a', dbname='a')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('try_create', ())
print cur.fetchall()
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure which will create a table named `hello`. I am invoking the same using a python script. Upon running the above script I see the following output

```
[root@localhost partitioning]# python test.py
[(1,)]
```

But the table is not created at the db. Am I making something wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [commit the transaction,](http://psycopg.org/docs/connection.html) add the commands:

```
...
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Alternatively, you can set the connection in autocommit mode:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='a', password='a', dbname='a')
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.callproc('try_create', ())
conn.close()
```

Read more about [transactions in psycopg2.](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control)

Comment: Thanks. It was a really a silly mistake from my side.