# dynamic query psycopg2 - table isnt created but no error raised

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a partition table in postgresql 10 via psycopg2.  The name of the table is a variable that I'm getting as a parameter. I dont get any error but the table isnt created :

```
     def create_partition(day,month,year):
        cursor=connect_db()
        relname='log_full_'+year+'_'+month+'_'+day
        range_day=year+'-'+month+'-'+day + ' 00:00:00'
        partition_range_day=datetime.strptime(range_day,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")    partition_range_next_day=datetime.strftime(partition_range_day+timedelta(days=1),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        partition_range_day=str(partition_range_day)
        partition_range_next_day=str(partition_range_next_day)
        cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) from pg_class where relname like %s",(relname,))
        rows=cursor.fetchall()
        if int(rows[0][0])==0:
                 cursor.execute(sql.SQL("create table {} partition of log_full(end_date) for VALUES from (%s) TO (%s) partition by list (start_stop)").format(sql.Identifier(relname)),(str(partition_range_day),str(partition_range_next_day),))
```

I tried also changing the syntax of the execute command but the result is the same :

```
cursor.execute("create table %s partition of radius_log_full(end_date) for VALUES from (%%s) TO (%%s) partition by list (start_stop);" % relname,[str(partition_range_day),str(partition_range_next_day)])
```

I didnt get any error and the table wasnt created..
In the serverlog of my postgresql database I saw the next output :

```
[2018-02-07 13:12:47 IST] LOG:  duration: 10.618 ms  statement: create table "log_full_2018_02_01" partition of log_full(end_date) for VALUES from ('2018-02-01 00:00:00') TO ('2018-02-02 00:00:00') partition by list (start_stop);
```

when I run this command at the psql client interface the table is created. Moreover, it didnt create the table on a different schema because I queried pg_class and I didnt find the relation.

My question is what is wrong in my code and what is the best solution for dynamic queries and why ? My psycopg2`s version is 2.7.1

Comment: You mean the first method that I used ? If not, can you specify what do you mean ?

Comment: I see. However, I want to do it via python so it is not helping me. thanks Vao.. :)

Comment: When you ran the create table command in psql, did you use exactly the same username? If not, it is possible that the schemas are different.

Comment: You should commit the transaction, see [Psycopg2 : Create a table in a stored procedure Postgres.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112371/1995738)